# Read XML file which has xmlns in tag with python

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to read a element form a xml file to add new elements.

The tag I'm trying to find contains xmlns.

It looks like this:

```
<labcore.logging.service defaultSystemIdentificationCode="??" xmlns="http://schemas.com/labcore/configuration">
<storage databaseName="COMIT" storageType="Oracle" />
<logEventDefinitions>

            <logEventDefinition assembly="IM.LogEventDefinitions" />                    
            <logEventDefinition assembly="BarcodeEntry.LogEventDefinitions" />                  
            <logEventDefinition assembly="MaintenanceScheduling.ActivityLog.Messages.LogEventDefinitions" />
            <logEventDefinition assembly="InCore.LogEventDefinitions" />    


  <logEventDefinition assembly="LogEventPackage.LogEventDefinitions" />
</logEventDefinitions>
```

and my python code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

def modifyComitLoggingConfigFile(filePath, fileName):

    path = filePath+"\\"+fileName

    IM = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    IM.attrib["assembly"] = "IM.LogEventDefinitions"

    BarcodeEntry = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    BarcodeEntry.attrib["assembly"] = "BarcodeEntry.LogEventDefinitions"

    MaintenanceScheduling = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    MaintenanceScheduling.attrib["assembly"] = "MaintenanceScheduling.ActivityLog.Messages.LogEventDefinitions"

    RTCosmo3 = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    RTCosmo3.attrib["assembly"] = "InCore.LogEventDefinitions"

    tree = xml.parse(path)
    rootElement = tree.getroot()

    loggingTag = rootElement.find("labcore.logging.service")
    print "loggingTag"
    print loggingTag
    print

    logEventDefinitionsTag = loggingTag.find("logEventDefinitions")
    print "logEventDefinitionsTag"
    print logEventDefinitionsTag
    print

    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, RTCosmo3)
    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, MaintenanceScheduling)
    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, BarcodeEntry)        
    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, IM)

    print "definitionfilesTag"
    print logEventDefinitionsTag
    print

    print "xml.tostring of definitionfilesTag"
    print xml.tostringlist(logEventDefinitionsTag)
    print

    tree.write(path+"1")
    return
```

and at the following line:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

def modifyComitLoggingConfigFile(filePath, fileName):

    path = filePath+"\\"+fileName

    IM = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    IM.attrib["assembly"] = "IM.LogEventDefinitions"

    BarcodeEntry = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    BarcodeEntry.attrib["assembly"] = "BarcodeEntry.LogEventDefinitions"

    MaintenanceScheduling = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    MaintenanceScheduling.attrib["assembly"] = "MaintenanceScheduling.ActivityLog.Messages.LogEventDefinitions"

    RTCosmo3 = xml.Element("logEventDefinition")
    RTCosmo3.attrib["assembly"] = "InCore.LogEventDefinitions"

    tree = xml.parse(path)
    rootElement = tree.getroot()

    loggingTag = rootElement.find("labcore.logging.service")
    print "loggingTag"
    print loggingTag
    print

    logEventDefinitionsTag = loggingTag.find("logEventDefinitions")
    print "logEventDefinitionsTag"
    print logEventDefinitionsTag
    print

    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, RTCosmo3)
    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, MaintenanceScheduling)
    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, BarcodeEntry)        
    logEventDefinitionsTag.insert(0, IM)

    print "definitionfilesTag"
    print logEventDefinitionsTag
    print

    print "xml.tostring of definitionfilesTag"
    print xml.tostringlist(logEventDefinitionsTag)
    print

    tree.write(path+"1")
    return
```

and on the following line:

```
loggingTag = rootElement.find("labcore.logging.service")
```

the following error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

but when i remove the `xmlns` part from the tag, it works. does anybody know how i can solve this?

Comment: I suggest that you try using lxml instead (it's largely the same interface).

Comment: i solved it, but im not sure if it will work. i have to add the namespace and put it before every tag im trying to find and format it. i will put the code in about 7 hours :) because i can not answer my own question, i dont have 100 reputation points :( Marcin, thanks for your tip, but i have to use the internal libs.

Comment: Not directly related, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876855/using-fromstring-with-lxml-prefixes addresses another aspect of namespace pain with lxml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix, uri)`

So

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace("lc", "http://schemas.com/labcore/configuration")
```

Then when you're searching for elements, use the prefix before the element name

```
loggingTag = rootElement.find("lc:labcore.logging.service")
```

Comment: no this is not working @hcayless. Error: raise SyntaxError("prefix %r not found in prefix map" % prefix)
SyntaxError: prefix 'lc' not found in prefix map

Comment: do you have an idea what it could be? because your solution looks much better :)

Comment: ahh.. i got it, this feature is new in Python 3.2. Im using 2.7.2, thats the reason. so your solution should also work. my works with 2.7.2. thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment, here is one solution that worked. but im not sure now, if the service will still work, maybe i can test it today or on monday.

solution is: 
add namespace to a variable:

```
namespace = "{http://schemas.com/labcore/configuration}"
```

and then when you call find.. add {0} before the searching tag and format it.

```
loggingTag = rootElement.find("{0}labcore.logging.service".format(namespace))
```

this you have to add for all childs.

im not sure if the service will work after that because he puts to every tag a ns:tagname.
but i think it would work.

root element is now:

```
<configuration xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.com/labcore/configuration">
```

childs are now:

```
<ns0:labcore.logging.service defaultSystemIdentificationCode="??">
```

If will give feedback if it worked or not. but hopefully it will :)