# using fromstring() with lxml prefixes

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I have a variable ele. I'm trying to append a child node onto ele that contains a namespace prefix (called style) in its tag. ele seems to be aware of this prefix, as the line:

```
print(ele.nsmap['style'])
```

outputs

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0
```

But when I try to run

```
ele.append(etree.fromstring('<style:style />'))
```

I get the error

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix style on style is not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm so glad I finally found this question with the terms "lxml from string with prefix" - I would have thought this was a bigger pain/problem and there would be lots of info (or at least a mention in http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`etree.fromstring('<style:style />')` throws an error because `<style:style />` is a small XML document that is not [namespace-well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#Conformance).

You have to declare the namespace in the document if you want to provide it as an argument to `fromstring()`:

```
etree.fromstring('<style:style xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" />')
```